# JQuery If any of the classes width is greater than 0

Tags: jquery

Here's what I've tried

```
    if($('modal').css(width) > 0)
```

Trying to write a simple if statement to check if any elements of the class "modal"'s width is greater than 0.

**EDIT**: This was really poorly written, sorry for that. Here's what I know I have to do:

I need to iterate over all the elements with class .modal in the DOM tree and just make sure that none of them have a width of greater than 0. I guess given this circumstance I could just have a for loop that would set all the widths to 0 of anything with class .modal.

**Got it! Here's what worked:**

```
 $(".modal").width(function(i, w) { return w * 0 });
```

Thanks for everyones help!

Comment: why w * 0 if it is always w*0=0? Shouldn't it just be `$(".modal").width(function() { return 0 });` ? Or even `$(".modal").width(0);` I'm not criticizing, just wondering if there is a reason for it...

Comment: I ended up going with $(".modal").width(0);. Realized the same thing as you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to find ids of items of a certain group (use a jquery selector like ".modal") that have width greater than one (to be safe I used 1 instead of 0).

As an example I have used:

```
    <div id="a" class="modal">aaaa</div>
    <div id="b" class="modal"></div>
    <div id="c" class="modal">cccc</div>
    <div id="d" class="modal"></div>
```

With `.modal {float:left}` in the CSS (otherwise all elements have same width).
You may use `if(testIfItemsWithWidth(".modal")) {...}` to just test for the existance of at least one.

```
    $(function() {
        if(testIfItemsWithWidth(".modal")) {
            alert("YES");
        }
    })



    function testIfItemsWithWidth(classes) {
        var foundOne=false;
        $(classes).each(function(cnt,itm) {
            if($(this).width()>1) {
                foundOne=true;
            }
        });
        return foundOne;
    }
```

[TRY HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/xMWJ2/)

If you want to do fancier things:

```
    $(function() {
        var items=getItemsWithWidth(".modal");
        for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++) {
            // as an example, display id in dialog and set their border to red
            alert(items[i]);
            $("#"+items[i]).css({"border":"1px solid red"});
        }
    })

    function getItemsWithWidth(classes) {
        var itemList=[];
        $(classes).each(function(cnt,itm) {
            if($(this).width()>1) {
                itemList.push($(this).attr("id"));
            }
        });
        return itemList;
    }
```

[TRY HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/vcbHy/1/)

Or better, you could use JQuery filter function:

```
    $(function() {
        var $items=$(".modal").filter(function(idx) {
            return ($(this).width()>1);
        }).css({"border":"1px solid red"});
    })
```

This just sets the border color to red as an example.

[TRY HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/WBqh7/)

Comment: Marked as correct despite finding a much simpler solution because my original question was very poorly written and non-specific. Cheers